# Hybris Spartacus after login via OpenID IAS cant reach from backend side current user

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We are using Hybris spartacus (3.0). We added app.module.ts following configuration for loggin sso via ias. When we open login page it redirects auto sso page we loggin and redirect to website. We can see Local Storage information idtoken userid. But we need backend side (occ side)current user information. When we call getCurrentUser method we cannot reach user which authenticate with openid. Do you have any comments for this ?

```
authentication: {
    client_id: environment.clientId, // this should be the client_id used in IAS
    client_secret: 'fakeClient', // The client secret is needed to fulfill the API contract for certain flows.
    //Never put here a real value as this is publicly available in the internet.
    baseUrl: environment.iasURL + '/oauth2', // The base URL defines, where to redirect.
    tokenEndpoint: '/token',
    loginUrl: '/authorize',
    logoutUrl: '/logout',
    OAuthLibConfig: {
      issuer: environment.iasURL,
      responseType: 'token',
      scope: 'openid',
      redirectUri: environment.baseUrl,
      customTokenParameters: ['token_type'],
      oidc: true,
    },
  },
```

[image from local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgGAw.png)

Comment: I found some cdc code i try use this codes like this.authStorageService.setItem('access_token', token.access_token);  But when i send token which i get from ias side access token backend system send this error. INFO  [hybrisHTTP3] [HybrisOAuthTokenStore] Failed to find access token for token eyJzdWIiOiJFWF9LT0VHQ0VTIiwibWFpbCI6InNpbmFuLmtvZWdjZUBkb2VobGVyLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9heDF2a2J3YTEuYWNjb3VudHMub25kZW1hbmQuY29tIiwibGFzdF9uYW1lIjoiS29lZ2NlIiwidHlwZSI6ImVtcGxveWVlIiwibm9uY2UiOiJjVE5rTFMxTFJWQTJWRmhCV21WQmJFaFBVVFpwZEhnMlZ6QlpXVlJMZEcxTlZ

Answer (score 1):

When you get the redirect from the SSO you get the token (and maybe additional parameters) which you then should use for the auth/token call against Commerce. Here a implementation of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter` (which you maybe need to implement?) should then take care of verifying this token etc. Make sure the grant_type maps to your TokenGranter.